# SQL Server hierarchyid Vs Closure Table

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data, hierarchyid

I'm implementing a organizational chart in SQL Server 2016 as a hierarchical structure. I have to do read, insert, update on the tree. I also have to get the subtree faster.

I looked at few different ways to implement this. The first and foremost, I thought about **hierarchyid**. Then I came across a couple of different ways that **Joe Celko** mentioned in his book **SQL Anti-Patterns** [image]

I also see another method mentioned at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/.

My questions are:

1. Doesn't hierarchyid do what a closure table does?
2. Does using hierarchyid make query slower?

Comment: I personally like hierarchyid and if that's the "path enumeration" line item in the provided chart, it absolutely can do referential integrity. And for ancestor/descendent type queries given a specific element, it's pretty fast. What issues are you seeing?

Comment: I'm looking for the existing feature of SQL and don't re-invent a new structure. So, I think HierarchId will work. Do you know whether I can use hierarchyid to create a graph like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397641/converting-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-to-tree/6486793?